# Simplifying Trigonometric Quotient

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I cannot seem to simplify the following:

$$\frac{2\cos(2x+h)}{\sin(2x+2h)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\sin(2x+2h)^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin(2x)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\sin(2x)^{\frac{2}{3}} }$$

simplified to:

$$\frac{2\cos(2x)}{3\sin(2x)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Please format using MathJax. See here for a reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's not true (eg take $x=0$). Are you sure you don't mean "Evaluate when $h=0$?"

Comment: @Dave, Thanks for the link! I'm new to the formatting but will be sure to code it properly in the future.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, That is exactly what I was I was missing... Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $h$ get very small and approach $0$.  The numerator is easy; what do you notice about the denominator (especially the middle term)?